# Using "Open with" on windows applications

Tags: windows, winapi, programming-languages

Let's say I'm making my own programming language, and it has its own scripting file extension.

Then the user, let's say, drags their script file of whatever program they made onto the .exe of the programming language

How, programmatically, could the programming language figure out how to use the fact that they "opened the script" by dragging it on the .exe, as a means to run the script?

Comment: If you drop a file on an executable Explorer runs that executable with the path to the file as its argument.

Comment: The "Open With" option comes into play only if you want to **right-click** on the script file and select which program to open it with.

Comment: I assume the "Open With" option works the same as dropping the script on the exe, as in adding the script path to the command arguments